# Draw UIBezierPath That Fades at Ends (Gradient)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, drawing, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw a `UIBezierPath` that fades out at both ends - from alpha `0` to `1` then back to `0`. I basically want to be able to **draw a gradient in a UIBezierPath from within `drawRect`**.

EDIT: Here's the effect I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a path that is filled with such a gradient or do you want to draw the gradient along the stroked line of the path?

Comment: I'm assuming the OP is talking about stroking a path. If the path was closed (and filled) it wouldn't have any ends.

Comment: @omz Yes, I want to stroke a path with a gradient.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for any path or just a simple line like in your image?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Just for a simple line.

Comment: What about using -strokeWithBlendMode:alpha:? this should work combined with a some sort of loop that keeps incrementing/decrementing the alpha value until you reach the 1 (and the increment determines the length of the "faded" segment).

Comment: you could also apply a mask using the _mask_ property of your view's layer, although that is resource intensive.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `-strokeWithBlendMode:alpha:`?

In combination with some sort of loop that keeps incrementing/decrementing the alpha value until you reach the 1 (and the increment determines the length of the "faded" segment) should work.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html)